# Git создать репозиторий и подключиться к нему с другой машины

Tags: git, git-clone, git-init

Есть машина с выделенным IP. Нужно создать на ней репозиторий и коннектиться с других машин.

Есть git init - с этим все понятно, и git clone - если работать с гитхабом с ним тоже все понятно, используешь URL репо, и вперед.

Что вводить вместо URL репо  в моем случае?

Comment: Вы б сначала протокол выбрали, по которому намерены подключаться к удалённой машине :)

Comment: @D-side, SSH, я думаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример.

на сервере (доступном извне по имени *server.tld*) создаёте bare-репозиторий в каталоге `repo` в домашнем каталоге пользователя `user` от имени этого пользователя:

```
$ git init --bare ~/repo
```

с другой машины клонируете этот репозиторий:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@server.tld/~user/repo
```

здесь `~user/repo` — это путь к репозиторию на сервере, строка `~user` означает домашний каталог пользователя `user`.

другой вариант указания *url*:

```
$ git clone user@server.tld:repo
```

---

более удобным средством создания, управления и использования набора git-репозиториев мне представляется использование набора скриптов *gitolite*. одноимённый пакет присутствует в большинстве популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

Comment: Мне кажется, это уже двадцатый раз, когда вы рассказываете про bare-репозитории )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, поиск подсказывает, что всего лишь на один ответ больше, чем вы (9 и 8 соответственно).

Comment: Да уж, популярная тема ))